# Loopback NodeJS - Check user role on log-in

Tags: node.js, rest, http, loopback, apiconnect

I have an application using Angular 5 for the front-end, NodeJS for the back-end and I am using loopback with it to create APIs. I have a remote method which I use to log-in the user, this works. Now I wanted to change this method to also check if the user is an admin, however I am unable to do so. For some reason when I make an API call to the RoleMappings model, using /api/RoleMappings?filter={where: {"principalId": ID_VALUE} it does not work. The ID_VALUE is also the user_id of the admin as this role and the admin are created programatically, so I know for should that the principalId is the userId.

I am making the request to check for the role as nested request, first I check if the user is logged in (if the user does not even log in there is no point in checking if he is an admin), then I check if that user happens to be the admin. This is the code, any help would be appreciated.

I tested the API call using IBM API connect, and it worked, it just doesn't want to work from my code. This request does not throw an error, but the response contains a 400 code and the body is empty.

The DB where the rolemappings are stored is a CloudantDB

```
var options = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: conf.endpoint + 'api/Clients/login',
            headers: this.headers,
            body: user,
            json: true
        }

        request(options, function (error, response, body) {
          if (error) return callback(error);

            //
            var adminOptions = {
            method: 'GET',
            url: conf.endpoint + '/api/RoleMappings',
            qs: {filter: {"where":{"principalId": "\""+body.userId"\"","roleId":"159882e4a5bdde9cc725eee8c13a1030"}}},
            headers: this.headers 
          }

          request(adminOptions, function(aReqErr, aRes, aBody){
            if(aReqErr) return callback(aReqErr);

            //console.log("Admin check success: ", aRes);
            if(aBody){
            var pId = aBody[0].principalId;
            console.log("Admin check success:", aBody);
            if(pId){
                body["isAdmin"] = true;
            }else{
                body["isAdmin"] = false;
            }
        }else{

            console.log("aResCode", aRes.statusCode);
            console.log("aResMessage", aRes.statusMessage);
            //console.log("aReqErr", aReqErr);
        }

          });

          //console.log('Success: ', typeof body);

          callback(null, body);

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would double check that the `RoleMapping` model is exposed publicly in `model-config.json`, which would be required to send the GET request.

I've got a similar query done in model code, which looks like this:

```
app.models.RoleMapping.find({
  where: {
     principalId: userId,
     roleId: roleId
  }
}, cb)
```

Given that your filter string looks like this:

`?filter={"where":{"principalId":<userId>,"roleId":<roleId>}}`

I'd expect it work based on my experience. Only other thing I can think of is maybe the formatting for the `userId` isn't correct, you could try dropping escaped quotes around it to just look like this:

```
qs: {
  filter: {
    where: {
       principalId: body.userId,
       roleId: "159882e4a5bdde9cc725eee8c13a1030"
    }
  }
}
```